# spark- how to select random rows based on the percentage of a column value

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to select random samples based on a distribution of a column using spark sql? For example for the dataframe below, I'd like to select a total of 6 rows but about 2 rows with `prod_name = A` and 2 rows of `prod_name = B` and  2 rows of `prod_name = C` , because they each account for 1/3 of the data? Note that each product doesn't always account for 1/3 percent. It's just an example. Many thanks for your help.

```
prod_name | value
----------------------
   A      | 100    
   A      | 200.    
   A      | 300
   A      | 400
   B      | 500
   B      | 600     
   B      | 650   
   B      | 700   
   C      | 500
   C      | 600     
   C      | 650   
   C      | 700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [sampleBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions.sampleBy.html) should do it. The required fractions for each `prod_name` can be calculated by dividing the expected number for rows by the actual number of rows:

```python
df=...
prods=df.select('prod_name').distinct().collect()
cnt=df.count()
expected_rows=6 # change this number to adjust of rows in  the result
fractions={r['prod_name']:expected_rows/cnt for r in prods}
df.stat.sampleBy('prod_name', fractions).show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+-----+
|prod_name|value|
+---------+-----+
|        A|  200|
|        A|  400|
|        B|  500|
|        B|  700|
|        C|  500|
|        C|  700|
+---------+-----+
```

The size of the result might not exactly match the number of `expected_rows` as the sampling involves random operations. The result will vary a bit.